# Can one keep both version of Flex builder simultaneously (verision 3 and version 4) on his/her machine

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flash-builder, gumbo

I have Flex builder 3 already installed on my machine. Now, I want to use Flex builder 4 also (officially Flash BUilder 4) on same machine. Can I directly start with Flex builder 4 and import my Flex BUilder 3 project there w/o any loss ? If not then, do I need to first uninstall my current version (3) or can I keep both the builder versions simultaneously ?

Also, are there any pre known concerns with the migration ? Will it improve/degrade the performance ?

If any one has tried this before, please help me.

(My system has XP professional, Intel core 2 Duo, 2 GB RAM ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've got both installed on osx...everything seems fine, but I haven't migrated projects back and forth between the two yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep both versions active at the same time. However, don't bother trying to migrate projects back and forth between the two, it will not work out well :)

If you want to keep a project active in FlexBuilder 3 after migrating, I'd recommend creating a branch to maintain it, and check out from there to do bug fixes etc. Continue in the trunk with your upgraded Flex4 project.

Providing you are using two completely separate Eclipse or [Flash|Flex]Builder installations you won't have any issues.

Comment: Why would anyone care about creating a Flex Builder 3 project archive active?  If a Flex 3 version is needed, Flash Builder has a multiple SDK feature that supports any version of the Flex SDK.  Then you'll still be able to take advantage of many of the improvements in Flash Builder 4.

Comment: Why indeed. ... elaborate cargo-culting?